# Who is ubuntu-etherpad and why did they take ownership of my bzr branch?

Tags: launchpad, bazaar

I created a project in bazaar:

```
# - On Effex - Desktop
cd ~/Proj
bzr init-repo cups-pdf
bzr branch ubuntu:precise/cups-pdf precise
bzr branch ubuntu:quantal/cups-pdf quantal
bzr branch ubuntu:raring/cups-pdf raring

bzr init cups-pdf-zel
gedit notebook.txt (and some notes)
bzr add .
bzr commit -m 'Update Notes'
```

I then pushed it once to the my [ppa junk folder](https://code.launchpad.net/~lantzr/+junk/cup-pdf-zel):

```
bzr push lp:~/+junk/cup-pdf
```

This worked great, aside from the typo I made typing `cup-pdf` instead of `cups-pdf`. I was able to go to launchpad and look at the branch.

```
http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~lantzr/+junk/cup-pdf-zel/
```

The configuration inside the `~Proj/cups-pdf/cups-pdf-zel/.bzr` folder still shows the same basic target

```
.bzr/branch/branch.conf
push_location = bzr+ssh://bazaar.launchpad.net/~lantzr/+junk/cup-pdf-zel/
```

I was able to access the ppa from my laptop.

```
# Sapphire - Laptop
bzr checkout http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~lantzr/+junk/cup-pdf-zel/
```

I made a trivial change to the note, then committed and pushed up the changes

```
bzr push
```

Please note that I did not check via the web interface at this time

And then ...

The next day my package has [moved](https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-etherpad/+junk/cup-pdf-zel). It is now owned by `ubuntu-etherpad` though I am listed as both registered and as a subscriber.

The configuration inside the `.bzr` folder on my laptop (Sapphire) shows a bound location to the etherpad url

```
.bzr/branch/branch.conf on Sapphire
bound_location = bzr+ssh://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-etherpad/+junk/cup-pdf-zel/
bound=True
```

Who is `ubuntu-etherpad` and why did they take ownership of my ppa?

Comment: I found this https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-etherpad and this https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Etherpad . Not sure how helpful that is to you.

Comment: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-etherpad owner is @JorgeCastro, active here too. Perhaps he can explain something. :) It seems that the complete Bazaar branch is now owned by that team, not just your PPA.

Comment: No clue what happened here, I'm waiting for someone who is launchpad-smart to answer this.

Comment: <laughing> I finally found a missing question.

This really did confuse me and I find no mention of it anywhere. As I have been poking around I've got more clues and will try to keep enhancing the question.

A missing piece from initial /, that I thought trivial, is that I tested my brand new ppa by logging into Launchpad from my laptop and checking it out. I believe that Launchpad is treating me from a different computer as a different human.

Comment: Not sure exactly how but the answer is somewhere around the two computers and that launchpads "One Signon" ...

XRef http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-etherpad/+junk/cup-pdf-zel/changes

It shows me as two different people.

Working theory here ...

Two authors => Non-Private Active Public repository

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't a PPA; it's a bzr branch.

You are indirectly a member of the ubuntu-etherpad team. See [your team membership information](https://launchpad.net/~lantzr/+participation).

This presumably means that you can write to this team's bzr branches, which you appear to have done unintentionally. Can you delete from https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-etherpad/+junk/cup-pdf-zel too, using the web interface?

Can you try being explicit when you push? Use, for example:

```
bzr push lp:~lantzr/+junk/cup-pdf
```

Does this work as you expect?

Edited to add: so I don't think ubuntu-etherpad has taken ownership of anything; you have been pushing and accessing its bzr branches all along, instead of your own as you intended.

Comment: Sounds credible, but the `push_location` was already explicitly referring to a personal branch, right?

Comment: `push_location` was overridden by the explicit destination that he specified on the command line when he pushed.

Comment: It was a ppa as rev 1 'bzr push lp:~lantzr/+junk/cup-pdf'. I believe that either the checkout or the push from my laptop (rev 2)  chaned things. I added my checkout command to the question, it was to the full address . For the push i just used 'bzr push' figuring like git bzr would know. Because of that i do not know if it changed owners on the checkout or push.

Comment: @Robie Ok from my laptop (rev 2 machine) I changed the note and pushed exactly as you asked. 'bzr push lp:~lantzr/+junk/cup-pdf'. It did push rev 3 through which shows on "lp:~ubuntu/+junk/cup-pfd". I confess I thought it would complain that I was not using cup-pdf-zel but it just changed the name to what I pushed. Xref the answer below. I currently believe I made ubuntu-etherpad owner (moved it from ~lantzr to ~ubuntu-etherpad) when I set the status to Experimental.

Answer (score 2):

You changed the owner of the branch to ubuntu-etherpad at 03:53 UTC on the 11th. You can change it back the same way, using the "Change details" link on the branch page.

Also, as others have hinted, that's a branch, not a PPA or a package.

Comment: Ok so when I did the checkout from my laptop it changed 

The push is recorded in rev 2 as 
Date: 2013-02-11 04:15:41 UTC

Comment: No, you did it by clicking "Change details" on the branch's Launchpad page and changing the owner option there.

Comment: on the branch's Launchpad page (as it is right now) the  pencil icon next to the "Experimental" status has the exact same url as the button you are citing. The status button pops up a dialogue listing only status changes. I _did_ change this to Experimental and definitely before I did the checkout.  That dialogue does not mention changing the owner or I would have cancelled it.https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-etherpad/+junk/cup-pdf-zel/+edit

Comment: You loaded the edit form, changed the owner, and then submitted the form -- you didn't just use the Experimental status popup.